# Representing a bounded linear functional on $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I have a question on this problem, and note it is for homework.

> Let $p,q$ be conjugate exponents. Define $H\colon L^p([0,1])\to \mathbb{R}$ by 
>   $$
>   Hf=2\int_0^1\left(\int_x^1 f(y)\,dy\right) x\,dx.
> $$ 
>   Find a function $g\in L^q([0,1])$ so that 
>   $$
>   Hf=\int_0^1fg \,dx.
> $$

Riesz representation theorem comes to mind, but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Fubini Theorem indeed:

$$2\int_0^1\left(\int_x^1 f(y)\,dy\right) x\,dx = 2\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^y x f(y) \,dx\right) \,dy = \int_0^1 y^2 f(y) dy.$$

Thus

$$Hf = \int_0^1 y^2 f(y) \,dy$$

and so $g(x) = x^2$.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it. I need to remember to always try and apply Fubini first.